# Gitlab. Не удается выполнить pull из локального репозитория

Tags: git, gitlab

В качестве репозитория к проекту добавлено локальная директория из каталога gitlab, сам проект располагается на одном сервере с репозиторием.

Директория проекта

```
/home/myuser/myproject/
```

Директория репозитория

```
/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/dir/myproject.git
```

с правами

```
drwxrwx--- 6 git git  4.0K Jan 17 23:15 myproject.git
drwxrwx--- 6 git git  4.0K Jan 17 23:13 myproject.wiki.git
```

пользователь, от которого выполняется пул, состоит в группе `git`

```
groups myuser
myuser : myuser cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev git
```

Однако, при попытке пула получаю ошибку

```
fatal: '/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/dir/myproject.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Что я упустил?

Answer (score 0):

Вы должны указать полный путь к файлу, тогда получиться склонировать репозиторий.

К примеру должен быть такой путь:

```
git clone ssh://user@ip/var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/dir/myproject.git
```

Если клонировать через http, то путь будет примерно такой:

```
http://ip/dir/myproject.git
```

Вообще в Gitlab когда переходите на страницу репозитория показывает путь ssh и http если конечно всё настроено правильно.

Попробуйте обратиться через `file`:

```
git pull file:///var/opt/gitlab/git-data/repositories/dir/myproject.git/
```

Хотя ваш вариант должен был сработать тоже, и даже если локально находится Gitlab не вижу проблемы через http забрать репозиторий

Comment: А если ssh, например, отсутствует?

Comment: Через http ещё позволяет gitlab клонировать

Comment: @andreymal да, кстати, про ssh комментарий в тему. это локальная папка на сервере - проект располагается на одном сервере с репозиторием. ответ немного не в тему. я пояснил особенности в вопросе

Comment: после вашей правки отмечу еще раз - у меня локальный репозиторий